Laravel - LiveWire with FullCalendar try to refresh showing events
I have a page with a LiveWire componant for showing Fullcalendar events. The page is working well, the events are showing and i can change month,weeks and the activites a loaded well.
I'm lost and confused, and seriously stuck. If someone can help me its will be fantastic.
I can see on the network tool debugger some update fire, but nothing changing on screen.
The composant View :
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use App\Models\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Livewire\Component;

class UserCalendrier extends Component
{
    public $events = [];
    public $show = true;
    public $showAnniversary = true;
    public $start;
    public $end;

    protected $listeners = [
        'triggerShowCalendar',
        'refreshCalendar'
    ];

    public function triggerShowCalendar()
    {
        $this->show = true;
        $this->events = $this->fetchEvents($this->start, $this->end);
        return view('livewire.calendar');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.calendar');
    }

    public function fetchEvents($start, $end)
    {
        $this->start = $start;
        $this->end = $end;

        $start = Carbon::parse($this->start);
        $end = Carbon::parse($this->end);

        if( $this->showAnniversary ) {

            $users = User::whereBetween('anniversary', [$start, $end])->get();

        } else {

            $users = User::whereHas('activities', function ($query) {
                $query->whereBetween('start', [$start, $end]);
            })->get();
        }

        $eventsGrouped = [];

        foreach ($users as $user) {

            
                $eventsGrouped[] = [
                    'id' => $user->id,
                    'start' => $this->showAnniversary ? $user->activities->start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') : $user->anniversary,
                    'start' => $this->showAnniversary  ? $user->activities->end->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') : $user->anniversary,
                    'title' => $this->showAnniversary ? $user->activities->title : $user->name.'anniversary'
                
                ];
        
       
        }
        return array_values($eventsGrouped);
    }


    public function eventDetail($user_id, $debut)
    {
        $this->dispatch('triggerShowDetailActiviteEleve', [$user_id, $debut, 'calendar-calendrier']);
        $this->show= false;
    }

    public function filterAnniversary()
    {
        $this->showAnniversary = !$this->showAnniversary;
        $this->events = $this->fetchEvents($this->start, $this->end);
        $this->dispatch('refreshCalendar');
        return view('livewire.calendar');
    }

    public function refreshCalendar()
    {
        $this->events = $this->fetchEvents($this->start, $this->end);
        return view('livewire.calendar');
    }
}

The Livewire view component
<div>
  
    <div style="{{ $show ? '' : 'display: none' }};">


        <button wire:click="filterAnniversary" class="btn btn-light-primary">{{ $showAnniversary ? 'Hide anniversary' : 'Show Anniversary' }}</button>

        <div id='calendar-container' wire:ignore >
            <div id='calendar'></div>
        </div>
    </div>


    @push('scripts')


        <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.6.0/main.min.js'></script>
        <script>

            document.addEventListener('livewire:initialized', function() {
                let calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
                let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
                    theme: false,
                    disableDragging: false,
                    disableResizing: false,
                    firstDay: 1,
                    weekends: true,
                    locale: '{{ config('app.locale') }}',
                    aspectRatio: 2,
                    noEventsMessage: 'no activities',
                    displayEventEnd: true,
                    slotEventOverlap: false,
                    headerToolbar: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
                    },
                    eventLimit: false,
                    views: {
                        agenda: {
                            eventLimit: 15
                        }
                    },
                    eventClick: info => {
                        @this.eventDetail(info.event.id, info.event.extendedProps.debutBrut);

                        //calendar.render();
                        @this.on(`refreshCalendar`, () => {
                            calendar.refetchEvents();
                        });

                    },
                    selectable: true,
                    selectHelper: true,
                    editable: false,

                    eventContent: function(arg) {
                        let customColor = arg.event.extendedProps.eventColor;
                        if (customColor) {
                            arg.backgroundColor = customColor;
                            arg.borderColor = customColor;
                        }
                    },
                    //events: JSON.parse(@this.events),
                    events: function(fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {
                        @this.call('fetchEvents', fetchInfo.startStr, fetchInfo.endStr)
                            .then(events => successCallback(events))
                            .catch(error => failureCallback(error));
                    },
                    dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
                        alert(date.format('DD-MM-YYYY'))
                    },
                });

                calendar.render();

                window.addEventListener('refreshCalendar', () => {
                    calendar.refetchEvents();
                });


            });
        </script>
        <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.6.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    @endpush
</div>

But, i'm trying to understand how to refetch the events on the calendar, by two others way, by a simple button "filterAnniversary", and after a event detail was showed.
Thanks for your help

From what I see there are some small corrections to make:
On the PHP side
In the fetchEvents() method
$users = User::whereHas('activities', function ($query) {
    $query->whereBetween('start', [$start, $end]);
})->get();

should be:
$users = User::whereHas('activities', function ($query) use ($start, $end) { 
    $query->whereBetween('start', [$start, $end]);
})->get();

Also when you fill the $events Grouped[] variable in the foreach loop, you set the 'start' key twice: the second should be 'end'
I also think that the strings set for 'start', 'end'' and 'title' should be swapped, for example:
'start' => $this->showAnniversary ? $user->anniversary : $user->activities->start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),

The array_values($eventsGrouped) is not needed you can simply return the $eventsGrouped variable

At class level:
return view('livewire.calendar'); must be removed from every method except render() because every time the frontend invokes a backend method render() is automatically executed - among other things if the render() method has the sole function to return the view with a standard name it can also be omitted

On the javascript side:
in the eventClick property, the event handler statement @this.on('refreshCalendar'..... must be removed because this sets a new one every time a click is made.
eventClick can become like this:
eventClick: information => {
    @this.eventDetail(info.event.id, info.event.extendedProps.debutBrut);
},

However it is not clear where the info.event.extendedProps.debutBrut property comes from and where the triggerShowDetailActiviteEleve event raised int the eventDetail() method is handled

Note that you have already set the code to handle the refreshCalendar event:
window.addEventListener('refreshCalendar', () => {
    calendar.refetchEvents();
});


Finally, keep in mind that the 'end' data provided by the calendar corresponds to the day following the period to be considered ( See here ) when composing the queries

Hi, Thanks for your answer. I really have somes troubles to understand how Fullcarlander is working with Livewire, even i allready have used Fullcalendar in a laravel project, but using JS :O
For the some mistake on the code it's because for the topic a have remove some logic to make it's simplier, but i'ts worst, sorry.
I have add somes details in a new answer. Thanks again for your help

In your request you said almost nothing about how you want to handle the calendar event when you select it. eventDetail() on the PHP side, dispatches the triggerShowDetailActiviteEleve event for which you have not shown the management, therefore it is not possible to give a precise answer. Since you have rightly set wire:ignore for the calendar container, you don't have to worry about the HTML sent from the backend, but only the data, because the calendar content is handled by the javascript library
